# How to change application icon in WinUI 3 C++?

Tags: winui-3

What is the easiest way to change the WinUI 3 C++/WinRT application icon? I'd like to see either XAML or C++ code that can be used to set the application icon by specifying the location of the icon file. thanks..........

Comment: What have you tested? This is the official way https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowing.appwindow.seticon

Comment: After adding `winrt::Microsoft::UI::Windowing::IAppWindow appWindow = AppWindow(); appWindow.SetIcon(L"h.ico");` and "#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Windowing.h>" in pch.h, and updating all packages that come by default with the project to the latest version everything worked. thanks.

Comment: You should answer yourself if you're happy.